# Using class through std::function

Tags: c++11

I have a question about using a specific class through C++ 2011 std::function in a producer/consumer environment. The producer uses a class `Invokable` that keeps specific information; the consumer *invokes* the class instance passing the proper information.
My implementation is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class Args {
    std::vector<std::string> opts_;

public:
    Args() {}

    Args& operator<<(const std::string& arg) {
        opts_.push_back(arg);
        return *this;
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return opts_.empty();
    }

    std::size_t size() const {
        return opts_.size();
    }

    const std::string& arg(std::size_t index) const {
        return opts_.at(index);
    }
};

class Invokable {
    std::string arg_;

public:
    Invokable() : arg_("none") {}

    bool operator()(Args& args) {
        if (args.empty() == false) {
            arg_ = args.arg(0);
            std::cout << "Invoked with arg '" << arg_ << "'\n";
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    const std::string& arg() const {
        return arg_;
    }
};

class Consumer {
    Args args_;

    std::vector<std::function<bool(Args&)>> signatures_;

public:
    Consumer() {
        args_ << "15" << "18";
    }

    void addInvokable(std::function<bool(Args&)>& sig) {
        signatures_.push_back(sig);
    }

    void run() {
        for (auto& sig : signatures_) {
            sig(args_);
        }
    }
};

class Producer {
    Consumer& user_;
    Invokable invokable_;

public:
    Producer(Consumer& u) : user_(u) {}

    void request() {
        std::function<bool(Args&)> sig {invokable_};
        user_.addInvokable(sig);

        user_.run();
    }

    void verify() {
        std::cout << "Invokable has arg '" << invokable_.arg() << "'\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    Consumer consumer;
    Producer producer(consumer);

    producer.request();
    producer.verify();

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the output produced is:

`Invoked with arg '15'
Invokable has arg 'none'`

That is, why the `Invokable` instance has not been updated by the consumer?

Answer (score 0):

`std::function` copies the held function object when it is copied.

You can use `std::ref` to get reference semantics (`std::reference_wrapper<callable>` is also *Callable*. Note that it is up to you to make sure that the reference doesn't out-live the referred object [1]

```
std::function<bool(Args&)> sig {std::ref(invokable_)};
```

I would also suggest changing `Consumer::addInvokable` to take by value and `std::move` into the vector, as a non-const ref is unidiomatic for copying.

```
void addInvokable(std::function<bool(Args&)> sig) {
    signatures_.emplace_back(std::move(sig));
}
```

This also removes the need for a local holding the initial `std::function`

```
user_.addInvokable(std::ref(invokable_));
```

1. In this case means that `producer` and `consumer` have to have the same lifetime. There is a reference "cycle" where a `Consumer` is held by a `Producer`, and a subobject of that `Producer` is held by that `Consumer` after `request` is called.

Comment: Very appreciable answer. Thank you.

Comment: I've added a note about reference lifetimes that doesn't matter in this *specific* instance (`producer` and `consumer` both live for the duration of `main`), but can be a gotcha

Comment: do you think the _classical_ approach with interfaces and dynamic inheritance has some advantage over the std::function approach?

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
  std::function<bool(Args&)> sig {invokable_};
```

when function object is created, it is initialized by copy of `invokable_`. If you want to avoid creating copy of `Invokable` object, you should use `std::ref` to create `reference_wrapper` which contains pointer to `invokable_`.

```
  std::function<bool(Args&)> sig { std::ref(invokable_) };
```

then if you call your function object, all changes will be applied to `invokable_` object instead to its copy.